A chaotic function related to the $3x+1$ problem? (Li-Yorke and the Collatz problem)
Let $ x $ be an infinite binary string. Define the function $ f(x) $ mapping $ x $ to the Cantor set of $ I = [0,1] $ as:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2 x_n}{3^{n+1}}
$$
where $ x_n $ are the bits of $ x $. Define the function $ g(x) $ over the interval $ I $ as:
$$
g(x) = \min_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |3x - 2n|
$$
which simplifies to:
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
3x & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{3} \\
2-3x & \text{if } \frac{1}{3} \leq x \leq \frac{2}{3} \\
3x-2 & \text{if } \frac{2}{3} \leq x \leq 1 
\end{cases}
$$
This function $g$ maps the Cantor set to itself and has the property that for each infinite bitstring $ x $:
$$
g(f(x)) = f(s(x))
$$
where $ s(x) $ is the Bernoulli shift of the bitstring $ x $, defined as $ s(x) = (x_{n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} $.
Using this observation, and denoting $ \text{CB}(q) $ the Collatz-Bits / Parity sequence bits of infinite length of the rational number $ q $, then:
$$
g(f(\text{CB}(q))) = f(\text{CB}(T(q)))
$$
where $ T\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = \frac{3(a/b)+1}{2} $ if $2$ occurs in the prime decomposition of $ a \cdot b $, $ \gcd(a, b) = 1 $ and
$$
T\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = (\frac{a}{b}) / 2 
$$
otherwise.
Using this last observation and induction on $ n $, it is possible to map iterations of $ T $ to iterations of $ g $:
$$
g^n (f(\text{CB}(q))) = f(\text{CB}(T^n(q)))
$$
The interesting part is that the function $ g: [0,1] \to [0,1] $ defined over the whole interval shows a chaotic behaviour as defined by Li-Yorke in 1975, because of the simple fact that it has a point of period three: $ \frac{1}{13} $ with trajectory $ \frac{1}{13}, \frac{3}{13}, \frac{9}{13}, \frac{1}{13} $. Here are more examples : (Table 1).



x
alpha_x
f(x)
g(f(x))




[0]
0
0
[0, 0]


1
-1
1
[1, 1]


[1, 0]
1
3/4
[3/4, 1/4, 3/4]


[0, 1]
2
1/4
[1/4, 3/4, 1/4]


[1, 0, 0]
1/5
9/13
[9/13, 1/13, 3/13, 9/13]


[0, 1, 0]
2/5
3/13
[3/13, 9/13, 1/13, 3/13]


[0, 0, 1]
4/5
1/13
[1/13, 3/13, 9/13, 1/13]


[0, 1, 1]
-10
4/13
[4/13, 12/13, 10/13, 4/13]


[1, 1, 0]
-5
12/13
[12/13, 10/13, 4/13, 12/13]


[1, 0, 1]
-7
10/13
[10/13, 4/13, 12/13, 10/13]



The Collatz conjecture might be formulated as:
The natural number $n$ with infinte bitstring $x:=CB(n)$ has an eventually periodic sequence $g^{k}(f(x))$ which ends in a period $1/4,3/4$.
The Theorem of Li-Yorke (1975) states that in some specified sense:

If the function has a period three point, then it is chaotic.

This could maybe describe the observed "chaotic" behaviour of the Collatz $ T $ map as defined above.
For each finite $x$, let $\bar{x}$ denote the infinite bitstring with pure period $x$. We define $\alpha_x$, which is a 2-adic number, by the following expression:
$$
\alpha_x := -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{3^{x_0 + x_1 + \cdots + x_n}} \cdot 2^n
$$
This formulation is borrowed from the discussion in Lagarias book where it is defined for finite strings. Here, we extend the concept using the 2-adic valuation for infinite bitstrings. Additionally one can use this function to prove that:
If $z = x.\bar{y}$ is an eventually periodic bitstring with period $y$, with lengths $r=|x|,s=|y|$, then
$$-\alpha_z = \frac{\rho_r(\alpha_x)}{\lambda_r(\alpha_x)}-\frac{\alpha_y}{\lambda_r(\alpha_x)}$$
and so, after some algebraic manipulations and since $\lambda_r(\alpha_x) = \lambda_r(\alpha_z),\rho_r(\alpha_x) = \rho_r(\alpha_z),$ :
$$\alpha_y = \alpha_z \lambda_r(\alpha_z) + \rho_r(\alpha_z) = T^{(r)}(\alpha_z)$$
where the last equality follows similar to the equation in Lagarias book, and $\lambda, \rho$ are copied as definitions from Lagarias $3x+1$ book.
But $y$ is periodic with period length $s$ so:
$$T^{(s)}(\alpha_y) = \alpha_y = \cdots = T^{(r)}(\alpha_z)$$
which proves that also in this case $\alpha_z$ must be eventually periodic.
The transformation $T$ on 2-adic numbers can be simply defined as:
$$
T(y) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{3y+1}{2} & \text{if } y_0 = (y \mod 2) = 1, \\
\frac{y}{2} & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $y_0$ is the 0-th bit of $y$. Thus, if $y_0 = 1$, then the transformation is $\frac{3y+1}{2}$; otherwise, it is $\frac{y}{2}$. This definition aligns with both the rational numbers' definition and the usual treatment for natural numbers, demonstrating its consistency across different numeric systems.
Q1: I have read some of the material of Lagarias and searched for a connection to chaotic functions in the sense of Li-Yorke and the Collatz problem, but could not find anything. Is there some literature covering this topic?
Illustration of the trajectories of $3$ (green) and $27$ (red) under the map of $f$:


related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474255/finding-a-two-point-scrambled-set-for-the-function-g0-1-rightarrow-0-1-x

Yes, if you read Lagarias and Bernstein 2019 it contains a proof that the Collatz function $(3x+1)/2$ or $x/2$ over the 2-adic numbers is topologically conjugate to the bit shift map (give or take glueing together the endpoints of the unit interval).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation This constitutes another proof of your above claim that it is chaotic and contains cycles of every order... as well as every possible infinite trajectory.

@it'sahirecarbaby: Thanks for the pointer.

You may already be aware of this but it's related so I'll mention it: The Lyndon words enumerate the priodic points of the above function and you can see they correspond with the solutions in your table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word . This implies there is a topological space over the Lyndon words which describes the orbits of such functions (its phase space?). These also correspond with the quadratics via their continued fraction representations and the set of rectangle-shapes which are eventually periodic via the truncation of a square from their end.

@it'sahirecarbaby: Thanks for this insight. I admit, I was not aware of these insights, so I have to think slowly about them to understand what you mean. But it is nice to see such connections.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714361/ .  Note that I probably spoke wrongly above.  Lyndon Words enumerate the periodic sets not the periodic points. So where you have six in your table of period three, only the two $001$ and $011$ represent Lyndon words, because the others $010$, $100$, $110$, $101$ are all rotations of the Lyndon Words.

@it'sahirecarbaby: Thanks for the hint. I was googling about "Lyndon words" and "Collatz" and found some interesting article. Kind regards, Orges
